# question about photographic effects on iphone

Tags: ios, camera

I'm interested in implement of photographic effects on iphone.
Taking [Camera+](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id329670577?mt=8) as an example, I'd like to know how to do the function of "Scenes", "Effects" and "Borders".

I'm fresh about it and just know it is in image processing domain.
I'd like to know where to start if I want to do it myself on iPhone.
Can you give any tip?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably start by reading up on the [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1) graphics engine and [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the main image class in Cocoa Touch. If you're starting with no knowledge of image processing, you'll have a lot of learning to do before you think about writing an image processing application.

Comment: is there any open source? Thank you.

Comment: @scorpiozj, there's plenty of open source image processing software in the world. You could look at the source code for [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org), for example, and that'd be a pretty good way to really learn about image processing. I doubt that anyone is going to hand you source code for an app like Camera+, though. The closest you'll get is Apple, which provides a lot of really powerful image manipulation tools in iOS. Start to learn to use them by reading the documents I linked.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to start image processing and applying effects to photos for iPhone apps is by using the [Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) technology that comes with Mac OS X and iOS 5.

With the Core Image, Apple provides you various [filters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346) that does all the pixel level processing needed. You can use these filters individually or combine them to create your effects.

The [Photo Effects SDK](http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801?ad=8699) may also ease your development further. It is built on the Core Image framework, comes with prebuilt effects and with an easy filter chaining support to create your custom effects.